# Is there a way to add directory to DataTransferItemList?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to simulate drag and drop event with a directory.

What I excatly want to do is convert canvas into file, put it into directory and dispatch drag event.

All of it is done by extension that works on specyfic site. I can drop there directory "img" with "icon.png" manually from file explorer. Drag data is being handled on that site by `webkitGetAsEntry()`.
Works similar to [example on this site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItem/webkitGetAsEntry).

Here's how I can simulate dropping just 1 file:

```
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);

canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
    let dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
    let file = new File([blob], "icon.png"); 
    dataTransfer.items.add(file);
    document.querySelector(".drop-zone").dispatchEvent(new DragEvent('drop', {dataTransfer}));
});
```

But how to make webkitGetAsEntry see dropped data as directory?
For example /img/icon.png